# Replacing XML contents and writing to disk

Tags: xml, perl, libxml2

I have a large xml of which I want to replace one of the attributes of node. I have a code which replaces the value of the attribute for the given node but it does not write to disk. I am not sure how should I make those changes propagated to disk?

For e.g: example.1.xml

```
<chairman name="abc" >
<vicechairman name="def">
<employee name="ghi" salary="123" designation="xyz"/>
</vicechairman>
</chairman>
```

In above example, I would like to change the value of employee nodes with  "salary="123"" attribute to "salary="456"" such that above xml changes to:

```
<chairman name="abc" >
<vicechairman name="def">
<employee name="ghi" salary="456" designation="xyz"/>
</vicechairman>
</chairman>
```

I have following piece of code which after getting to node of "employee" changes the Attribute value to "salary=456", but does not write to disk:

```
foreach my $anode (@attributes){
    my $attr = $anode->nodeName;
    if($attr eq "salary"){
        $anode->setValue( "456" );
    }
}
```

Any help will be Appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML%3a%3aLibXML), explicitly write the revised contents to disk:

```
# save
open my $out, '>', 'out.xml';
binmode $out; # as above
$doc->toFH($out);
# or
print {$out} $doc->toString();
```

Comment: Would this copy my entire xml contents as is changing only the one of the attribute values? I am not sure how this would work?

Comment: Any reason to not use $doc->toFile?

Comment: Any output method would work, Zaid.  Just wanted to list two of the options.

Answer (score 0):

With XML::Twig:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $old_sal="123";
my $new_sal="456";

XML::Twig->new( twig_roots => { qq{employee[\@salary="$old_sal"]} 
                                  => sub { $_->set_att( salary => $new_sal); $_->flush; } 
                              },
                twig_print_outside_roots => 1,
              )
         ->parsefile_inplace( 'emp.xml');
```

This updates the file inplace.If you don't want to update inplace, use `->print_to_file( 'out.xml')`

This will work without using much memory, as only the nodes that trigger the handler are loaded in memory (and removed once used, so you only have a single one in memory at any given time).

Comment: I believe this would work, but somehow I am restricted to using LibXML. Thanks for your help